# Display an image who is in bytes of array in my View

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

My goal is:

1. I load a person's data into a template that I send to my view.
2. The user can modify his data and click on 'Submit'.

Almost everything works as it should except for the image.
Indeed, in the method of my controller, I receive the image in bytes of array and I do not find how to display it in my view.
I found several explanations on the net where it is written that I have to use the URI scheme.

But I do not know how since my controller send this data in my code js.
I'd like to say that the input with @Model.Member_Picture contains exactly "value="System.Byte[]".

Could you enlighten me?

(I just post the code related to the image).

**Model**

```
[ContainerDataFor("Picture_gr")] // use the name in your C# model
public byte[] Member_Picture { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
            <div class="form-check-inline col-xs-6" style="margin-top:2%">
                <img id="ItemPreview" src="" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"/>
            </div>


            <div class="form-check-inline col-xs-6" style="margin-top:2%">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Member_Picture, "Upload Picture", new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "test" } })
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="file" id="file" value="@Model.Member_Picture">
                <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Maximum 1024kb</small>
            </div>


$(document).ready(function () {
    var img = $('#test').val();
    $('#ItemPreview').attr('src', `data:image/png;base64,${img}`);
});
```

Comment: Well, you cannot set an `<input type="file" />` like this: `<input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="file" id="file" value="@Model.Member_Picture">` because file input meant to select client file. You need to display it using `<img>` tag pointing to path where you save the file, or convert the byte array into base64 string and display it instead.

Comment: Thx for your help. The <input type='file'> was here to let the user upload another picture. I tough it could automatically been loaded with the actual picture but it seems not, i'll modify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your src to `src="data:image/png;base64, +data"` where the data is the byte array of the image

```
<img id="ItemPreview" src="data:image/png;base64, @Model.Member_Picture">
```

example

```html
<div>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAAEsBAMAAACLU5NGAAAAG1BMVEUAmf////8fpf9fv/8/sv+f2P/f8v9/zP+/5f8U6SNkAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAC1UlEQVR4nO3Xz0/aYBzH8doW8biOH3IsoswjDJd4bBnuTBez7GjN5nbUxOxMXaL+2fs+T4t92g6ywyO7vF8J7Ye0ha/fp34BxwEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMD/5c5mYRE/njVT02j2vkj+bN5IllwEQdC/1fUlQTAIq6nJl2PBDx1PJD3UkiWtwX3ong9UjA/n7q9ONTUlT3NnlK1UgcF9+C6dVJIt7Uht75bSon4omywy01/c66t6shley+a0W0l2HbyRx1uVxldm2ihTj1A27k0l2dWWQuKlTh0zbXQXOn4vTxMjWeZJWUmo48BMG01Dp6V76uytjGRZSxaxWIPMTEo7L9KLzAsSx9m/0knWv0yWDWXZ8pVQy1Mmfexa76Yr43xXTtnTS63Wv0x2uTdyqxzmeTopk9756v/S8SpLOpZSYz3sHK9jJKv85KF80XhSpmKv2lVp1oWateuqO0ay6OtjcCk7rxg7w9syFVVLu4xmtZ7TXqQKjfRT99BINst6Tr9H28pS7TKa1Xp+7F++flnyeue9rWX5/VF1WIyy5Q7KkrdYbivLidNV9Xyvt5Oy2t2XGzae+LVbXg4HYe2Cu2h9WM6OX+OWV2QOvYyFqEzrw9PsunaBDLr1WOgaybbB5nGqZlY+uwzyQfP649Rxfm7+8NEzK661a3+1iw8f1aC8OW4laWpm1dslDSqaMzSTZV5nyxcbPbNq7ZpOdvHFZl/+3gN9xw5XZtIl65lVa1cqz/TXV1cdLZMtJ+rd3GyiPq/lxd00MpNRXpzv3M9qe6o6Of6mNt1KsmU8ODsaJXokfOrNj5NuNQkv3/lhXlb6e370IVAjwU8vjy6CqJKsOZffUj39lu6XZmryMrlAt8w5SZvJGn/x8svzeNFMTYtFWCR3ETUSAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD4N38AsX524K81XMUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My actual problem is how can i get the value, like in your example? Because the @Model.Member_Picture only contain System.Byte[].
Should i create a new variable to convert the bytes of array in Base64 and display it?

Comment: @Korpin replace for string

Comment: base64 on c# is a string also you can read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToBase64String_System_Byte___

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `value` attribute inside `<input type="file" />` to render the image. You need to render the image as Base64 string with this setting:

```
@{
    var base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Member_Picture);
    var source = String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", base64Image);
}

<img src="@source" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Or create another string property like this:

```
public byte[] Member_Picture { get; set; }

public string Image
{
    get
    {
        return String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(Member_Picture));
    }
}
```

And show it in the view:

```
<img src="@Model.Image" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Comment: Yep what i did is create another variable and convert the bytes of array in Base64String and not it works! I guess i'll have to do the same when a user whant to update a picture?

Comment: Which method you want to update that picture (using normal form submit or AJAX)? If you want to use AJAX, then the `<img>` tag should be placed inside partial view and update it from controller action which returns partial view, otherwise normal form submit should change it after reload.

Comment: Yep, i wanted to do it with the normal form. Thanks for infos i'll read about how to make it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with vanilla Javascript:

```js
var fileInput = document.getElementById('img-input');
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var imageType = /image.*/;

  if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      demo.src= e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    demo.src = '';
    console.log('file not supported');
  }
});
```

```css
#demo {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#img-input {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="file" id="img-input" name="file"></div>

<!-- this is where we display the choosen image //-->
<img id="demo" src="#" alt="your image here" />
```